# Error undefined reference in build muPDF for android (need help)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, pdf-generation, mupdf

this is sample error in cygwin

> C:/mupdf-0.8.165/android/jni/../../mupdf/pdf_nametree.c:111:
> undefined reference  to `fz_array_get'
>
> C:/mupdf-0.8.165/android/jni/../../mupdf/pdf_nametree.c:112:
> undefined reference  to `fz_is_string'
>
> C:/mupdf-0.8.165/android/jni/../../mupdf/pdf_nametree.c:115:
> undefined reference  to `fz_dict_put'
>
> C:/mupdf-0.8.165/android/jni/../../mupdf/pdf_nametree.c:116:
> undefined reference  to `fz_drop_obj'

In pdf_nametree  include fitz.h
actually I check the function fz_array_get in fitz.h already

I have no idea now
Can anybody point me to the right direction or give me a another way

thx
sasara

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `%path%` variable (DOS) was not correctly translated to the `$PATH` (Cygwin) variable....

You need to install both the Android SDK as well as the Android NDK. Then you  need to add both `<sdk-install-dir>\tools` and `<ndk-install-dir>` to your `%path%` variable.

Also, you need Cygwin v1.7 or greater on Windows.

Then, look here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/msg/b385e47e1484c2d4 for 2 fixes which deal with bugs that occur for automatic conversion from DOS format path variables to Cygwin format path variables.